# I can't position the screen on a specific date with '$("# calendar"). FullCalendar (' gotoDate ', date);' in fullcalendar v.3.10 js/c#

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        var res = $("#txtSearch").val();
        res = res.substring(0,9);
        date = moment(res.val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);       
    }),
```

In frontend(Default.aspx):

```
<asp:Button  Text="Search" id="btnsearch" runat="server" />
```

but when i charge the event page start and end parameters are set to today's date.:

```
  public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
  {
           
          List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

          if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"]!= null) { 
             String user= System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Username"].ToString();
          }

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id_xEvent,description, title, event_start, event_end, all_day,color,place FROM xEvent where event_start>=@start AND event_end<=@end", con);
           // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT xDataConsRichiesta,xStatoAbbinamento,(convert(varchar,Id_DoTes)  + ' ' + 'data doc: ' + convert(varchar,[DataDoc],103) + ' codice doc: ' +  convert(varchar,[Cd_Do]) + '   tipo documento:' + convert(varchar,[TipoDocumento]) + ' codice cliente:' + convert(varchar,[Cd_CF])) as title ,(' codice cf dest:' + convert(varchar,[Cd_CFDest]) + ' codice cf sede:' + convert(varchar,isnull([Cd_CFSede],'')) +  ' data consegna: ' + convert(varchar,[DataConsegna],103) + ' data trasporto ' + convert(varchar,isnull([TrasportoDataora],''),103) + ' volume: ' +  convert(varchar,isnull([VolumeTotale],'')) + ' luogo scarico: ' + convert(varchar,isnull([Cd_DoLuogoScarico],'')) + ' tipo vettore:' + convert(varchar,isnull([xTipoVett],'')) + ' data cons richiesta: ' + convert(varchar,isnull([xDataConsRichiesta],''),103) + ' data consegna confermata:' + convert(varchar,isnull([xDataConsegnaConfermata],''),103)) as description      FROM [ADB_isolkappa].[dbo].[DOTes] where xDataConsRichiesta BETWEEN @start and @end", con);
          //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end, all_day,color FROM Event e inner join dotes d on e.event_id=d.cd_xabbinamenti inner join xabbinamenti a on d.cd_xabbinamenti=a.cd_xabbinamenti where event_start>=@start AND event_end<=@end", con);
          //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT (Cd_CF + ' ' + NumeroDocRif + ' ' + DataDocRif + ' ' + numerodoc + ' ' + xCaricoCompleto + ' ' + Cd_DoTrasporto + ' ' + xTipoVett + ' ' + Completo + ' ' + Data_Spedizione + ' ' + xDataConsegnaConfermata + ' ' + DataConsegna + ' ' + Cd_DoLuogoCarico + ' ' + Cd_DoLuogoScarico +' ' + xOKLogistica) as description, title, event_start, event_end, all_day, color FROM Event e inner join dotes d on e.event_id = d.cd_xabbinamenti inner join xabbinamenti a on d.cd_xabbinamenti = a.cd_xabbinamenti where event_start>= @start AND event_end<= @end");
    
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start;
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end;
          //SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand();
          //string stato="0";

          using (con)
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
              while (reader.Read())
```

The getEvents function is called in JsonResponse.ashx

```
 foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
        {
            tasksList.Add(new ImproperCalendarEvent {
                id = cevent.id,
```

update:now the code

```
$("#btnsearch").click(function () {
        var res = $("#txtSearch").val();
        res = res.substring(0,10);
        date = moment(res, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm");
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', date);
       }),
```

with in default.aspx:
Search

it is positioned on the requested date but inverting the month with the day.For example if I search for an event on 03/09/2021 (dd / mm / yyyy) it positions itself on the week starting on 08/03/2021

Comment: Does the btnSearch make a postback to the server? It looks like it probably does. If it does, then any jQuery code you wrote to handle it is irrelevant because the page is refreshed straight afterwards anyway.

Comment: P.S. How is the getEvents function related to the rest of the code? I don't see any kind of link.

Comment: excuse me ADyson,how you could get around this problem

Comment: Well, make a button which doesn't post back

Comment: Please Adyson,you can take a look at the update?Thanks

Comment: fullCalendar 3 accepts momentJS objects directly. You don't need to pass it a formatted string. If you _do_ pass it a formatting string, it will try to parse it. But it doesn't know what format you intended, so if you pass something like 03/09/2021 it doesn't know if you intended that to be in dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy format - how could it tell? So it defaults to treating it as mm/dd/yyyy (probably because that's the default in the USA and a general standard default in JavaScript). `date = moment(res, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm")` will work just fine`.

Comment: In general: Never use region-specific date formats without any context, and never put dates into _strings_ to pass information between two parts of a computer program (unless you need to serialise them for transmission over the network, or for storage). Dates should only be turned into formatted strings when you want to display them to humans. There are too many possible variations of the formats for computers to be able to understand them all. Instead, computer use _objects_ such as momentJS or JS Date objects which contain an internal, unformatted, and **unambiguous** representation of dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fullCalendar 3 accepts momentJS objects directly. You don't need to pass it a formatted string.

If you do pass it a formatted string, it will try to parse it. But it doesn't know what format you intended, so if you pass something like 03/09/2021 it doesn't know if you intended that to be in dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy format - how could it tell? So it defaults to treating it as mm/dd/yyyy (probably because that's the default in the USA and a general standard default in JavaScript).

```
date = moment(res.val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
```

will work just fine.